# How to use JavaBean and EntityBean?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, javabeans

I'm very confuse when I learn about JPA - Hibernate and EJB(EntityBean). Should I write JavaBean separate with EntityBean? I and my friend discuss this problem in very long time but it still not end! It look like the same but I want to separate it JavaBean for business logic and EntityBean just use for reflect to DB.

Answer (score 2):

You should use session beans (EJBs) to represent your business logic, as you say.  Entity beans should be used to represent persistent state.  In earlier versions of the standard (up until EJB 3.0) JPA was part of the EJB standard, but has since been moved into separate standard.